# Is it possible to search intellisense in vstudio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Is it possible to search or filter intellisense in visual studio?

Basically i know there is an enum in the project that contains 'column', but the enum doesnt begin with 'c'.

There has been lots of times where id rather not scroll through the hundreds (if not thousands) of valid objects it gives me.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if the real answer here is (and I won't be surprised to be voted down for this) that your enum isn't properly named. If it was then I'd expect the name to be obvious in the use context, may be consider renaming the enum?

Answer (score 1):

You can search in Class View. Type "column" and hit enter.

Visual Studio 2010 changes all of this, giving you multiple *very* easy ways to do this type of search quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ReSharper, you can use "Go To Symbol..." and type "*column*", and it will give you all symbols (types, properties, fields, methods, etc) that match.

Otherwise your best bet is to use the Object Browser and search.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know about doing that in intellisense itself, but assuming the objective is to actually find a member whose name you don't remember, you can write a small utility for that purpose using the underlying mechanism intellisense uses, reflection.

Comment: That, actually, would not be a "small" utility, especially considering VS has already two such tools built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Open the **Object Browser** under **View** menu. From there, you can search within all the language constructs available to you.